# Adding a counter on html file in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm showing the restaurants that are filtered by the name and the address. (if no name or address is given then all restaurants are shown). The problem is that I need to add a counter to count the remaining restaurants after each filter or the count of all restaurants if no filtering is done.

The code I used (works perfectly):

(app-res-tabs is a component that shows the restaurant)

```
  <div *ngFor="let res of restaurants;">

    <li
      *ngIf="(res.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString?.toLowerCase()) 
              || searchLength == false) 
              && (res.Address == printedOption || checked == false)"
      class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open">
      <a class="nav-link active">
        <app-res-tabs [res]="res"></app-res-tabs>
      </a>
    </li>

  </div>
```

How to add a counter for the restaurants in this code ?

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz with some dummy data

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdckek?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add index to the `*ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let res of restaurants; let i = index">
    <p> It is index of restaurants {{ i }} </p>
    <p> It is counter of restaurants {{ i + 1 }} </p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

You can create a variable `counter`:

```
counter = this.restaurants.length;

this.searchForm.controls['str'].valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
  this.searchString = value;      
  this.counter = this.restaurants.filter(f => 
       f.Name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase() 
       || this.searchLength == false) 
       && (f.Address == this.printedOption || this.checked == false)).length;
  if (this.searchString.length > 0) {
    this.searchLength = true;
  }
  else { this.searchLength = false }

});
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let res of restaurants; let k = index;">
    <!-- I want to show the count after this filter 
       (and the number of all restaurants if no filter is done) -->

    <li *ngIf="(res.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString?.toLowerCase()) 
        || searchLength == false) 
        &&(res.Address == printedOption || checked == false)"
        class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open">        
    <p>counter: {{ counter }}</p>
        <a class="nav-link active">
            <div>{{res.Name}}</div>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

[A work example at stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygdtjm?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: It returns the index of each restaurant from all the restaurants not from the remaining restaurants after filtering. I just need the number of remaining restaurants after filtering.

Comment: @AliHmede I am glad to help you!:)

Answer (score 2):

You can check this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvaeju?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

You have to check remaining length of autocomplete results and actual data of length. You can use reactive forms here...

```
this.remainingResults = this.booksName.length -  data.length;
```

Go stackblitz link for complete example

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a function that will return the filtered values.

```
getData(data){
   return data.filter(item => item.includes(yourSearchString));
}
```

Update filter function as per your requirement.

```
<div *ngFor="let res of getData(restaurants);let i = index">
<li
    {{i}}  
</li>
</div>
```